# How to configure IIS/web.config for Smart card login option (SITHS) and SSL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, certificate, smartcard

I have a site built in mvc3 using normal FormsAuthentication for login. This site should now be SSL-enabled, and I've also been asked to add the option to login using e-Identification/Smart card (my customers emploees all have specific eIdentification cards called SITHS).

- So I have a certificate from VeriSign for the SSL (installed).
- I have a Root "CA" certficiate for the server-client verification (added to trusted root).
- I have a test card with an e-identification certificate corresponding to the above root cert.

I have the code ready for the membershipProvider to parse and check the client certificate against my user database, but I'm very unsure about the server- and certificate bits. Also the old functionality of normal FormsAuthentication should be retained.

My idea is to enable SSL on the entire site using the VeriSign cert. Then, somehow, add a requirement for example "LogOnSmartCard.cshtml" to use the "CA" cert. So when a user is directed to this page the smart card application will kick in and an authentication will be made. Then I can create the normal login ticket and redirect the user to the main page.

If this seems like a decent idea - any ideas on how I should go about configuring this in IIS (v7) and/or web.config? Can I require a specific cert for a specific page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll add how I solved it since there was no other input:

- In IIS I bound the (SSL) VeriSign cert to the entire site
- I imported the CA certificate(s) for (smart card) authentication to the certificate store
- I added the IIS option "Require SSL" to a specific view for smart card login

By just doing these steps I have an SSL-encrypted site (https) and a view that requires, in my case, smart card login.

- In the code I added a ActionFilter (IAuthorizationFilter) that interprets the certificate and checks for validity (etc.) and then tries to perform a login against users mapped in the database (to the certificate serialnumber)
- Registered the ActionFilter in global.asax (Application_Start)

This solution, together with the normal FormsAuthentication, now works perfectly hand-in-hand.